# Exclude parent category when getting category posts by slug

Tags: categories, get-posts

I have the following category layout:

```
Resources
    -- Documents
```

I want to list the posts in the documents category, and have the following code:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'orderby'          => 'ID',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'category-name'    => 'documents'             
        );
$surveys = get_posts($args);
```

This returns the posts in both documents AND resources categories. I only want those in 'documents'.

I know there is ways to exclude categories by ID but I need to use the category slug as my dev and live databases do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if a single typo is messing things up for you? Please try this:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
        'orderby'          => 'ID',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'category_name'    => 'documents'             
        );
$surveys = get_posts($args);
```

where I replaced `category-name` with `category_name`.

> I know there is ways to exclude categories by ID but I need to use the
>   category slug as my dev and live databases do not match.

There exists for example the function [`get_category_by_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) that you can use if you need to get the `term_id` from the `slug`:

```
if( FALSE !== ( $obj = get_category_by_slug('some-category-slug') ) )
{
    $id = $obj->term_id;
}
```

Comment: Damn! I had looked at that over and over as well. Thanks for pointing that out.